# Why is my shuffle implementation incorrect?

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle

I use `random.shuffle` when I want to shuffle a sequence. I have read the source code of `random.shuffle`, it is a typical implementation of [Fisher–Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

However, I once saw an incorrect implementation of a shuffling algorithm. The code was the following:

```
def myshuffle(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    for idx in xrange(length):
        t_idx = random.randint(0, length-1)
        lst[idx], lst[t_idx] = lst[t_idx], lst[idx]
```

I know there is something wrong and I have tested it. But it is not clear to me why this is incorrect. Let's say `p[i][j]` means the probability of element move from pos `i` to pos `j`, can anybody make it clear?

Here is my test code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()

    pre_lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    count = dict((e, {}) for e in pre_lst)
    TRY = 1000000

    for i in xrange(TRY):
        lst = pre_lst[:]
        myshuffle(lst)
        for alpha in pre_lst:
            idx = lst.index(alpha)
            count[alpha][idx] = count[alpha].get(idx, 0) + 1

    for alpha, alpha_count in sorted(count.iteritems(), key=lambda e: e[0]):
        result_lst = []
        for k, v in sorted(alpha_count.iteritems(), key=lambda e: e[0]):
            result_lst.append(round(v * 1.0 / TRY, 3))
        print alpha, result_lst
```

And the result:

```
> a [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] 
> b [0.242, 0.18, 0.185, 0.192, 0.2] 
> c [0.21, 0.23, 0.173, 0.186, 0.2] 
> d [0.184, 0.205, 0.231, 0.18, 0.2]
> e [0.164, 0.184, 0.21, 0.242, 0.2]
```

Comment: Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: How are you seeding?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what is wrong with the algorithm, but you should probably think about the problem backwards, that is, can you demonstrate that the algorithm generates any permutation with the same probability? Or (equivalently, I think) that every element has the same probability to end up in any position? If not, it's just an heuristic (an algorithm that "intuitively" seems sensible but has not been proved to be correct).

Comment: "What's wrong" with the algorithm is that it doesn't correctly implement Fisher-Yates. The random index `t_idx` should not be between `(0,length-1)` it should be `(idx, length-1)`. In Fisher-Yates you do not shuffle the parts of the deck you have already covered (schwobaseggl's answer explains the problem you get with your current implementation and why it matters)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematically:

It is impossible for this algorithm to produce equally likely outcomes: This algorithm has `n^n` different ways to go through the loop (`n` iterations picking one of `n` indexes randomly), each equally likely way through the loop producing one of `n!` possible permutations. But `n^n` is almost never evenly divisible by `n!`. Therefore, this algorithm cannot produce an even distribution.

Compare that to [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) where at each of `n` iterations, the   pool of swap indexes decreases by `1`. Here, there are exactly `n!` paths through the tree, each resulting in exactly one of the `n!` possible permutations.

For short lists (`n <= 4`), you can draw both trees with pencil & paper.

### Empirically:

You can write a function that generates all `l**l` possible paths through the shuffle tree and then count the outcomes:

```
def shuffle_combos(lst, i=0):
  l = len(lst)
  for j in range(l):
    lst_ = lst[:]
    lst_[i], lst_[j] = lst_[j], lst_[i]
    if i == l-1:
      yield tuple(lst_)
    else:
      for perm in shuffle_combos(lst_, i=i+1):
        yield perm

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pprint(list(Counter(shuffle_combos([1,2,3])).items()))
[((1, 3, 2), 5),
 ((3, 2, 1), 4),
 ((2, 3, 1), 5),
 ((1, 2, 3), 4),
 ((2, 1, 3), 5),
 ((3, 1, 2), 4)]
#            ^- 3^3 = 27 paths, but 3! = 6 permutations
#            but 27 % 6 != 0
>>> pprint(list(Counter(shuffle_combos([1,2,3,4])).items()))
[((4, 1, 2, 3), 8),
 ((1, 3, 2, 4), 10),
 ((3, 4, 1, 2), 11),
 ((1, 2, 4, 3), 10),
 ((1, 2, 3, 4), 10),
 ((1, 3, 4, 2), 14),
 ((1, 4, 2, 3), 11),
 ((4, 2, 1, 3), 9),
 ((2, 4, 3, 1), 11),
 ((2, 1, 3, 4), 10),
 ((4, 2, 3, 1), 8),
 ((3, 1, 2, 4), 11),
 ((4, 3, 1, 2), 10),
 ((2, 4, 1, 3), 11),
 ((2, 3, 1, 4), 14),
 ((3, 1, 4, 2), 11),
 ((3, 4, 2, 1), 10),
 ((1, 4, 3, 2), 9),
 ((3, 2, 4, 1), 11),
 ((2, 3, 4, 1), 14),
 ((4, 1, 3, 2), 9),
 ((4, 3, 2, 1), 10),
 ((3, 2, 1, 4), 9),
 ((2, 1, 4, 3), 15)]
```

And you can see that they are not evenly distributed.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. And can you derive the formula of p[i][j]?I have tried it, but no result.

Comment: @xybaby You could derive it from the empirical case by summing up all counts where i was moved to j and divide by the total count